# How to select control to be focused from ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, focus

Consider the following form:

[image]

I want textbox1 or textbox2 to be focused when i click on "1" or "2" in the listview.

I wrote the following code:

```
  private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsSelected)
        {
            if (e.Item.Text == "1")
                textBox1.Focus();
            else
                textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. (Textbox gets focused for a moment, but after that the focus goes back to listview.)  I want the focus to be on textbox when I select the relevant item in the listview.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The behavior for Select is exactly the same  as for Focus().

Comment: Try to debug your app and look which element is stealing the focus.

Comment: Obviously listView itself is stealing the focus. How to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focus is being reset to the `ListView` because of the order the events are being fired.

1. MouseDown - Selects the item in the list view.
2. ItemSelectionChanged - Calls `listView1_ItemSelectionChanged`.
3. MouseUp - If the cursor is still over `listView1` this sets the focus to the list view.

Disabling the control will work, but it adds a 'flicker' when the item is clicked.  Otherwise, you can track the selected item on `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`/`MoustLeave` and set focus appropriately.

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsSelected)
    {
        if (e.Item.Text == "1")
            textBox1.Focus();
        else
            textBox2.Focus();
    }
    listView1.Enabled = false;
}

private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Enabled = true;

}

private void listView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Side note - do you need to use a `ListView`?  Did a quick test on my end and a `ListBox` behaves the way you want without any hacks.

Comment: I need something like this: ![Error List](http://s14.postimage.org/wyb7kj3j5/errorlist.jpg). How they did it?:)

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm, perhaps ListView is receiving focus again when it returns from the Focus/Select command. One way may be to use a timer/delayed callback and just trigger that - i.e. make it asynchronous, after say 50 ms, then ListView onclick event will have completed by the time control is passed.

Comment: Yes,thanks. This will work. But I don't like the approach much because of the timer.

Comment: Sure, me either. However, you may find this is internal to the LV control, it's not really meant for the use you are putting it to. You could use asynchrous event I suppose (but then you have the non Gui thread coms to sort out). Is there a reason to use LV? I have used a panel in the past and controlled icon layout and mouse position/events - this may be a better (although moren invovled) alternative???

Comment: I believe LV with similar behavior is used  in VS'S error list: ![Error List](http://s14.postimage.org/wyb7kj3j5/errorlist.jpg). Or maybe it is datagrid view,but there is no difference. But how they did it?

Comment: Have you tried triggering on the mouse up rather than the mouse down. If you are worreid about movement between the two, you can capture the position at mouse down and trigger focus on mouse up, then nothing should be called in LV to pull back control.